# Убрать запятую в конце генерирущихся элементов

Tags: php

Всем привет. Есть php код в котором автоматически генерируются элементы. Подскажите как после последнего элемента убрать запятую или поставить точку?

```
<?php $repeat_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'link_service', true );
            if ( $repeat_field ) {
            $values = explode( '| ', $repeat_field );
            foreach ($values as $value) {
            echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>, ';
            }
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соберите ваши ссылки в массив, а потом объедините полученные элементы в строку с разделителем `,`:

```php
$temp = [];
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $temp[] = '<a target="_blank" href="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
}
echo implode(', ', $temp);

// Если нужна точка в конце
echo implode(', ', $temp) . '.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Только не забудьте, что функция `array_shift` удаляет элемент из исходного массива.

```
<?php $repeat_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'link_service', true );
            if ( $repeat_field ) {
            $values = explode( '| ', $repeat_field );
            $value = array_shift($values);
            echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
            foreach ($values as $value) {
            echo ', <a target="_blank" href="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
            }
            }
```